# react native shopping cart with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Hello i just started redux with react native i am trying to make a food delivery app. each food has options like drinks or dessert for example. I would like that if the user adds a basket an items we check if the options chosen are the same to increase the quantity if they are not the same I would like to add another item with the new option to the global state. only I tried a lot of things and none seemed to meet my expectations. the structure of the data that I pass to the global state is in this form.

```js
cartProduct = [
  {
    id: itemId,
    restaurantName: restaurantName,
    name: itemName,
    quantity: quantity,
    price: price
    selectedOption: [
      optionId: optionId,
      itemId: itemId,
      name: itemName,
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is the code I wrote in the reducers with the add to cart action

```js
switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            const cartProductIndex = state.cartProduct.findIndex(item => item.id === action.value.id)
            if (cartProductIndex == -1) {
                nextState = {
                    ...state,
                    cartProduct: [...state.cartProduct, action.value]
                }
            } else {
                state.cartProduct[cartProductIndex].selectedOption.map(item => {
                    if (item.item === action.value.selectedOption.item) {
                        let newArray = [...state.cartProduct]
                        newArray[cartProductIndex] = {
                            ...newArray[cartProductIndex],
                            quantity: state.cartProduct[cartProductIndex].quantity + 1,
                            totalPrice: state.cartProduct[cartProductIndex].totalPrice + action.value.totalPrice
                        }
                        nextState = {
                            ...state,
                            cartProduct: newArray
                        }
                    } else {
                        nextState = {
                            ...state,
                            cartProduct: [...state.cartProduct, action.value]
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            return nextState || state
```

Comment: For a first post, thank you for showing all your code. I will show you what I would do below.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this.

```
switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_TO_CART':
  const cartProductIndex = state.cartProduct.findIndex(item => item.id === action.value.id)
  if (cartProductIndex == -1) {
    return {
      ...state,
      cartProduct: [...state.cartProduct, action.value]
    }
  }
                
  const newCartProduct = state.cartProduct[cartProductIndex].selectedOption.map(item => {
    if (item.item === action.value.selectedOption.item) {
      item.quantity++
     }
   
     return item
   })                      
   
   return {
     ...state,
     cartProduct: newCartProduct
   }
}
```

You cannot update the state in a map loop, a map returns a new array. You want to use map to create a new array, and then use that value. Once a function is complete you should return, you don't need that else.

Comment: thank you for your help I will try your solution hoping that it meets my expectations